# Building an array that combines indices and values in pairings

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider an array `a` whose rows hold unique values from 0 to 7, and no value matches its own column index.

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4],
              [1, 0, 7, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [4, 2, 1, 7, 0, 6, 5, 3]])
```

I plan to use `a` to build a new array `b` having the same shape.  The method of producing `b` is described below in a scaled-down example:

For each row of `a`, I need to:
i) select the values that are **greater than their index values**.  For the 1st row of `a`, this involves indices `0, 2, 3, 4`,  holding values `1, 5, 6, 7`.

ii) then I need to fill a new array `b` with rows that **combine the index and value pairings**.   The 1st row of `b` would be  `[0,1, 2,5, 3,6, 4,7]`.   (The unusual spacing is just to emphasize the index-value pairings)  The completed `b`  would be:

```
b = np.array([[[0,1, 2,5, 3,6, 4,7],
               [0,1, 2,7, 3,4, 5,6],
               [0,4, 1,2, 3,7, 5,6]])
```

I need help with an efficient way to build `b`.

Comment: Why are you certain that each row will have exactly 4 indexes with greater value? For example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0]` has 7?

Comment: If the answer to the above is positive, you can do `x,y = np.nonzero(a > np.arange(a.shape[1])); out = np.array([y,a[x,y]]).T.reshape(a.shape)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang you should post it as answer. Variant for the last step: `np.c_[y,a[x,y]].reshape(a.shape)`

Comment: @mozway, `np.c_...` will run slower (I got `~8.05 µs`), next one is `np.column_stack([...]).reshape(a.shape)` - `~3.09 µs`, and `np.array([...]).T.reshape(a.shape)` remains at most speed `~2.22 µs`

Comment: Interesting, I don't know it this scales the same way

Comment: Hi.  Yes, Al rows will have exactly the same number of matches, but it won’t necessarily be 4 as in the example.   The rows will always have an sven number of values, often 30 or 32.  Each row will always have the same number of matches.

Comment: thanks to mozway, QuangHoang, and RomanPerekhrest for a great collaborative response!  Very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by @QuangHoang in comments, your approach is only valid if you can assert that all rows will have the same number of matches.

In this case, use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and broadcasting to identify the values greater than their position, then concatenate with [`np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) the columns indices and values, and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
idx, col = np.nonzero(a > np.arange(a.shape[1]))

out = np.c_[col, a[idx,col]].reshape(a.shape)

# or for a faster variant
# credit to QuangHoang, and RomanPerekhrest for the timing
# np.array([y,a[x,y]]).T.reshape(a.shape)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6]])
```